# Convex and non-convex problems in machine learning

Tags: conv-neural-network, convex-optimization

In convolutional neural networks(CNNs), I read that activation functions like tanh are good only for convex problems/optimizations. What does it really mean? What are convex and non-convex optimizations? Why are convex problems "easier" to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what your first statement means. In a nutshell, the difference between convex and non-convex optimisation relies on the convexity of the functions describing the objective function and constraints. Convex optimisation problems have many benefits including: uniqueness of optimal point and computational tractability of the problem. I hope this gives you a first overview.

Comment: Thanks! Any links would be a lot more helpful.